# Insert into SELECT with composite primary key failing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have one very large, un-normalized table which I am in the process of fixing.  From that large table I'm normalizing the data.  I used the SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO smallTable(patientID, admissionDate, dischargeDate)
select distinct patientID, admissionDate, dischargeDate
FROM largeTable
```

So my smallTable is populated with the correct number of rows.  There's another column, `drgCode` that I want to add to my smallTable.  I tried the following query to do that

```
INSERT INTO smallTable(drgCode)
select drgCode from
(
SELECT DISTINCT patientID, admissionDate, dischargeDate, drgCode from largeTable) as t
```

The error I was given reads `cannot insert the value NULL into patientID, column does not alloq nulls, insert fails`.

The only way that the `drgCode` will be chosen correctly is if some variant of the `select distinct` query is used.  How can I insert only one field, when the other fields must be included to narrow down the search.

I know I could do this if I emptied out my smallTable, but I figured there's gotta be a way around it.

Comment: Does each patient only have one admission date? I.E. is patientid unique?

Comment: Why didn't you inserted that column on your first statement?. `SELECT DISTINCT patientID, admissionDate, dischargeDate, drgCode from largeTable`. Also, can there be more than one value of `frgCode` for each distinct values of `patientID, admissionDate, dischargeDate`?, if so, wich one should you choose?

Comment: @Lamak I forgot, and then I figured there's gotta be a unique way to get this to work.  I'm trying to learn more tricks of the trade for SQL

Comment: @joshp no, each patient can have more than one admission date.  I think I just need to delete the table and add it on the initial insert, I was just wondering if what I want is possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    with    drg as (SELECT DISTINCT patientID, admissionDate, dischargeDate, drgCode from largeTable)
    update  s
    set     s.drgCode = l.drgCode
    from    smallTable s join drg l on 
                s.patientId = l.patientId and
                s.admissionDate = l.admissionDate and
                s.dischargeDate  = l.dischargeDate
```

Comment: I knew there had to be something I was unaware about.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie this is the more correct answer. May I recommend that you upvote it and accept it as the answer?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - In your comments you said "same patientID can have more than one drgCode associated with it", so why did you accepted that answer instead of this one?

Comment: the query didn't run the first time, due to my typographical error.  credit is now given where it was due.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, if you have "PatientID" to be unique in both the tables, you can do something like below.

```
Update S
SET S.drgCode = L.drgCode
FROM
    SmallTable S
INNER JOIN
    LargeTable T
   ON S.PatientID = T.PatientID
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: that's not a bad attempt, but the same patientID can have more than one drgCode associated with it.  I suppose I could just go ahead and include the drgCode as part of the primary key.  But that I don't want my indexes to get too big..ugh..

Answer (score 1):

When you perform an insert to a table, any values not specified in the query are poulated with the default value for the column. If there is no default value on the column, NULL will be used. You recieved that particular error message because your column does not allow NULL and does not have a default.

Given your reply to Praveen, perhaps you should be further normalizing and put the drgCodes into a separate table.